# Getting issue for SSO to tomcat App using Shib SP

Tags: tomcat8, shibboleth-sp

I have a 3rd party application which is using Tomcat authentication for its session creation. I am planning to enable SSO to that application by integrating that with Shib SP. I am getting an error after enabling Shib SP with it.

I can not change anything in 3rd party application to consume shib headers. Let me know if it can work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not modify 3rd party app, then obviously you can not implement SAML/SSO there.

But probably there is workaround. Implement some 'wrapper' service over that 3rd party app which performs SAML authentication and creates user account in the 3rd party app and performs logging in into 3rd party app with that user account.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.